# can I store a Dictionary as the property of an object?

Tags: python, web-applications, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask

Using Python/Flask/SQLAlchemy/Heroku.

Want to store dictionaries of objects as properties of an object:

TO CLARIFY

```
class SoccerPlayer(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    goals_scored = db.Column(db.Integer())
```

^How can I set name and goals scored as one dictionary?

---

UPDATE: The user will input the name and goals_scored  if that makes any difference.

Also, I am searching online for an appropriate answer, but as a noob, I haven't been able to understand/implement the stuff I find on Google for my Flask web app.

Comment: What are you trying to do such that you need the data structure to be (theoretically) `soccer_player.data["name"], soccer_player.data["goals_scored"]` rather than `soccer_player.name, soccer_player.goals_scored`? (Knowing that will help improve the answer).

Comment: I want to compare one team's list of SoccerPlayer (s) to another team's SoccerPlayer (s) - in terms of goals scored. The player with the most goals scored on each team - will be outputted to the webpage.

Comment: I just thought that a dictionary would be useful. I also plan to add assists, fouls, etc. later on - so I thought it would get too cluttered to do it without a dictionary.

Comment: I would think that using the database's fields directly would work much better than packing up the data into a Python (or JSON) dictionary. Whatever sort of comparisons you want to do will surely be faster (and probably easier) done with DB queries, rather than with your own code working on the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing such information in a database I would recommend another approach:

```
class SoccerPlayer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Team.id'))
    stats = db.relationship("Stats", uselist=False, backref="player")


class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    players = db.relationship("SoccerPlayer")


class Stats(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('SoccerPlayer.id'))
    goals_scored = db.Column(db.Integer)
    assists = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # Add more stats as you see fit
```

With this model setup you can do crazy things like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

max_goals_by_team = db.session.query(Team.id,
                    func.max(Stats.goals_scored).label("goals_scored")
                ). \
            join(SoccerPlayer, Stats). \
            group_by(Team.id).subquery()

players = SoccerPlayer.query(Team.name.label("Team Name"),
                                SoccerPlayer.name.label("Player Name"),
                                max_goals_by_team.c.goals_scored). \
                join(max_goals_by_team,
                        SoccerPlayer.team_id == max_goals_by_team.c.id,
                        SoccerPlayer.stats.goals_scored == max_goals_by_team.c.goals_scored). 
                join(Team)
```

thus making the database do the hard work of pulling out the players with the highest goals per team, rather than doing it all in Python.

Comment: How would you initialize player_id for stats (i.e. how would you add it in a def __init__ method)

Answer (score 2):

I would second the approach provided by Sean, following it you get properly
normalized DB schema and can easier utilize RDBMS to do the hard work for you.  If,
however, you insist on using dictionary-like structure inside your DB, I'd
suggest to try out [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html)
data type which allows you to store key/value pairs as a single value in
Postgres.  I'm not sure if `hstore` extension is created by default in Postgres
DBs provided by Heroku, you can check that by typing `\dx` command inside
`psql`.  If there are no lines with `hstore` in them, you can create it by
typing `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;`.

Since hstore support in SQLAlchemy is available in version 0.8 which is not
released yet (but hopefully will be in coming weeks), you need to install it
from its Mercurial repository:

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy#egg=SQLAlchemy
```

Then define your model like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict

class SoccerPlayer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)
    stats = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))

# Note that hstore only allows text for both keys and values (and None for
# values only).
p1 = SoccerPlayer(name='foo', stats={'goals_scored': '42'})
db.session.add(p1)
db.session.commit()
```

After that you can do the usual stuff in your queries:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, cast

q = db.session.query(
    SoccerPlayer.name,
    func.max(cast(SoccerPlayer.stats['goals_scored'], db.Integer))
).group_by(SoccerPlayer.name).first()
```

Check out [HSTORE docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.HSTORE)
for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Not even django(a bigger python web framework than flask) doesn't support this by default. But in django you can install it, it's called a jsonfield( https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield ).

What i'm trying to tell you is that not all databases know how to store binaries, but they do know how to store strings and jsonfield for django is actually a string that contains the json dump of a dictionary.

So, in short you can do in flask

```
import simplejson

class SoccerPlayer(db.Model):
  _data = db.Column(db.String(1024))

  @property
  def data(self):
      return simplejson.loads(self._data)

  @data.setter
  def data(self, value):
      self._data = simplejson.dumps(value)
```

But beware, this way you can only assign the entire dictionary at once:

```
player = SoccerPlayer()
player.data = {'name': 'Popey'}
print player.data # Will work as expected
{'name': 'Popey'}
player.data['score'] = '3'
print player.data
# Will not show the score becuase the setter doesn't know how to input by key
{'name': 'Popey'}
```